# How to ensure the integrity of domain model in DDD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have a domain enity called country with following structure

```
 public class Country : Entity
    {
        public Country()
        {
            States=new List<State>();
        }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string CountyCode { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; private set; }

        public void AddNewState(State state)
        {
            if(IsDuplicateStateExists(state.GetHashCode())) throw new ApplicationOperationException(Messages.Validation_DuplicateState){HttpCode = 409};

            States.Add(state);
        }

        bool IsDuplicateStateExists(int hashCode)
        {
           return States.Any(x => x.GetHashCode() == hashCode);
        }

        public State GetStateById(int stateId)
        {
            return States.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == stateId);
        }

        public void DeleteState(int stateId)
        {
            var state = GetStateById(stateId); 
            if(state==null) return;
            state.CountryId = 0; // This is for informing EF to delete this object Check Orphan entities in EF
            States.Remove(state);
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

            if (CountryName.Length < 3) results.Add(new ValidationResult(Messages.Validation_CountryNameRequired,new String[]{"CountryName"}));
            if (CountyCode.Length < 2) results.Add(new ValidationResult(Messages.Validation_CountryCodeRequired, new String[] { "CountyCode" }));
            return results;
        }
    }
```

Here i have few doubts about the desing of this entity, 
1.) Can an entity throw an error ?

2.) Is it good idea to put validation ( not business rules) logic in enity

3.) "Country has states and every state must have county",
if this is one rule in design specification, Addnewstate(),IsDuplicateStatesExists(),RemoveStates () are eligible to keep inside country entity or should i moved to application service

Comment: This is too many questions in one, and it probably belongs on Programmers rather than StackOverflow which is more factual and less conceptual.

Comment: @ArtB, Almost every question related to DDD is opinion based , because it is a pattern, which has different styles of implementations. here i asked about my implementation is correct or not based on few given fact. all the questions are not extremely different but its related.

Comment: DDD is more processy and more open-ended so that's by I'd say Programmers is the better place for it. Don't get me wrong, I like your question, it's just not IMHO (and not just mine) the wrong place for it. They removed the option to flag questions to move to Programmers so you'll have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Can an entity throw an error?

Yes, of course. You can throw exceptions when business rules are violated.

2.) Is it good idea to put validation ( not business rules) logic in enity

I would prefer to put just business validations in entities. So I won't validate logic like string length in entities. Upper layer should validate non-business logic. But I think it's a good idea to use DataAnnotations like `[Required]`, `[StringLength]` in the entity, because they are so simple and make our life much easier :P

3.) "Country has states and every state must have county", if this is one rule in design specification, Addnewstate(),IsDuplicateStatesExists(),RemoveStates () are eligible to keep inside country entity or should i moved to application service.

Keep inside `Country` entity. But your implementation is incorrect. **Two different entities can produce same hashcode!** You can make your `States` property a set (`ISet<T>`) if you correctly implemented the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods of `State` class. But I would prefer to check duplicate simply base on state name.

Answer (score 0):

Entities are just data transfer objects. They tell Entity Framework what the database table should look like and give Entity Framework a place to dump the data it selects from that table. As such, they should only have business logic related to the database. For example, if a string column should be non-nullable, you can add the `[Required]` attribute to your property. Anything above and beyond that belongs *somewhere else*.

That "somewhere else" could be your repository, a service, or a view model. It it's business logic related to how an entity should be retrieved, for example, you'd put that in the repository or service. If it's business logic related to how a user should input data in a form, that belongs in the view model.

Comment: i am not asking about EF or its related techniques , i am asking about  Domain driven design concepts ,  "Entities are just data transfer objects" how this statement is valid in Domain driven design, is it good idea to consider POCO as domain entites in our domain model